# Place <ul> element to the right (fluid nav)

Tags: css

Iam trying to create a ul element which sticks to the right side of its parent div element.
The ul should be fluid, see what I've got so far below. Ul stays on the left, want it to start on the right, so that the li with the contact is fixed to the right corner.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgdx6z1/3/)

**Html:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>portfolio</li>
        <li>blog</li>
        <li>news</li>
        <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 0 0 5%;
}

ul li:after {
    content: "|";
    padding: 0 0 0 5%;
}

ul li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: You may add to UL selector a line: `text-align: right;`

Answer (score 1):

Know that i understant the problem you just need to add a `text-align:right` to the `ul` element.

```
ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
width: 100%;
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: That wouldnt affect my child ul element. The ul content still starts on the left

Comment: Then i'm not sure what you want to do.. If you you put `float:right;` all the div will be on the left side. it's alway easier to float a div. If you don't like this solution because you want to add more content do this div maybe do `<div><div class="{float:right class}"><ul>[...]>/ul></div></div>` if you only want the text to be align right then do : `text-align: right;` on the ul element.

Comment: this approach works if you add a `float: right` to "ul li" container but it makes a reverse menu items order